# Next.js is generating .html file even with getServerSideProps present?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

When I run the following code like so "http://localhost/myslug", the method runs twice, one of those times the slug is printed with an attached ".html" like "myslug.html"

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context : NextPageContext) {
    
     const { slug } = context.query;
     console.log('slug', slug);

     try{
          //some processing
     }
     catch(err){
          context.res.statusCode = 404;
          return{ statusCode : 404};
     }
}
```

My understanding is that since getServerSideProps is present, this would be only SSR (not SSG). Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be the fact that I also had

```
context.res.statusCode = 404
```

in the catch part of a try catch. For some reason, doing this made next do an extra request with .html appended to the URL. Removing this fixed my issue.